# Passing props and map

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, react-props

I need help! I am trying to map a props array but it says that 'props.map is not a function'

```
import React from "react";
import Track from "../Track/Track";
import './TrackList.scss';

const TrackList = (tracks) => {

    return(
        <div className="TrackList">
            {tracks.map((track) =>
                (<Track track = {track} key={track.id}/>)
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default TrackList;
```

Those props came from here:

```
    import React from "react";
    import TrackList from "../Tracklist/TrackList";
    import './SearchResults.scss';
    
    const SearchResults = (searchResults) => {
    
        return(
        <div className="SearchResults">
            <h2>Results</h2>
            <TrackList tracks = {searchResults}/>
        </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default SearchResults;
```

And SearchResults component is receiving them frop App.jsx:

```
import './App.css';
import{Playlist, SearchBar, SearchResults} from '../index'
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState(
    [
      {name: '1', artist: '1', album: '1', id:'1'},
      {name: '2', artist: '2', album: '2', id:'2'},
      {name: '3', artist: '3', album: '3', id:'3'},
      {name: '4', artist: '4', album: '4', id:'4'},
    ]

  );

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
      <div className="App">
        <SearchBar />
        <div className="App-playlist">
          <SearchResults searchResults = {searchResults}/>
          <Playlist />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The props array is arriving well in every component but map does not work...

Answer (score 1):

```
const TrackList = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className="TrackList">
            {props.tracks.map((track) =>
                return (<Track track = {track} key={track.id}/>)
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

and

```
const SearchResults = (props) => {
    return(
    <div className="SearchResults">
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <TrackList tracks = {props.searchResults}/>
    </div>
    )
}
```

I hope this will help you.
Thanks

Comment: Yes!Thanks but I also had to add a question mark:                                                                        
     return(
        <div className="TrackList">
            {props.tracks?.map((track) =>
                {return (<Track track = {track} key={track.id}/>)}
            )}
        </div>

Comment: So my code is not working without adding question mark?